# How to save data entered in textboxes and later used to do calculations when next button is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have a table inside a panel. The table has 32 rows and 4 columns. One column is a label and has a description. The other 3 are textboxes. A user can enter a number between 0 and 99 on any of the textboxes. None of the textboxes are required so user can choose not to enter anything.
After entries are made, user will click next button and calculations will be done and displayed in a new page. Before that happens, I want to know how to save all the data user entered. Then how do I read each saved row to do calculations? This is where I am stuck on how to either use a list int or List string to save in a session and how to calculate entered data from the session. Nothing is saved in the database.
**Sample code**

```
<table class="wizard">
<tbody> 
    <tr>
      <td class="blankcell" valign="bottom" align="left" width="39%">
      <span class="smalllabel">Available Service</span></td>
      <td class="blankcell" valign="bottom" align="right" width="10%">
      <span class="smalllabel">You</span></td>
      <td class="blankcell" valign="bottom" align="right" width="10%">
      <span class="smalllabel">Spouse</span></td>
      <td class="blankcell" valign="bottom" align="right" width="10%">
      <span class="smalllabel">Child</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grayservicebackground" align="left" valign="middle" style="width:39%;">
      <span class="servicefont">Preventive Physical Exam</span></td>
      <td id="SinglePreventivePhysicalExam" class="numberofserviceinputcell" align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:10%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSinglePreventivePhysicalExam" runat="server" value="0" maxlength="2" size="3" class="numberinput"></asp:TextBox>
      <cc2:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender0" runat="server"
      FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtSinglePreventivePhysicalExam" />
      </td>

      <td id="SpousePreventivePhysicalExam" class="numberofserviceinputcell" align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:10%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpousePreventivePhysicalExam" runat="server" value="0" maxlength="2" size="3" class="numberinput"></asp:TextBox>
      <cc2:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server"
      FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtSpousePreventivePhysicalExam" /></td>

      <td id="ChildPreventivePhysicalExam" class="numberofserviceinputcell" align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:10%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtChildPreventivePhysicalExam" runat="server" value="0" maxlength="2" size="3" class="numberinput"></asp:TextBox>
      <cc2:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server"
      FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtChildPreventivePhysicalExam" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="grayservicebackground" align="left" valign="middle" style="width:39%;">
      <span class="servicefont">Preventive Well Child Visit through Age 5</span></td>
      <td id="SinglePreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" class="numberofserviceinputcell" align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:10%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSinglePreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" runat="server" value="0" maxlength="2" size="3" class="numberinput"></asp:TextBox>
      <cc2:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender3" runat="server"
      FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtSinglePreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" />
      </td> 
      <td id="SpousePreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" class="numberofserviceinputcell" align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:10%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpousePreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" runat="server" value="0" maxlength="2" size="3" class="numberinput"></asp:TextBox>
      <cc2:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender4" runat="server"
      FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtSpousePreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" />
      </td>
      <td id="ChildPreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" class="numberofserviceinputcell" align="right" valign="bottom" style="width:10%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtChildPreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" runat="server" value="0" maxlength="2" size="3" class="numberinput"></asp:TextBox>
      <cc2:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender5" runat="server"
      FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtChildPreventiveWellChildVisitthroughAge5" />
      </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `ASP.NET Web Forms` ?

If you have `Viewstate` enabled, the textboxes will maintain the values in certain instances.

Your next button would have some sort of OnClick functionality tied to your code behidn right?

```
protected btnNext_Click(object sender, Eventargs e) {

  var value = txtSpousePreventivePhysicalExam.Text;

}
```

That's how you would get the value of a specific textbox.  You could then store that value in `Session` for instance to keep the value alive.

Comment: But I do not know how to save the values of the textboxes in a Session.

Comment: To save the value in session do this:  `Session["SpousePreventivePhysicalExam"] = txtSpousePreventivePhysicalExam.Text;` To retrieve the value: `txtSpousePreventivePhysicalExam.Text = Session["SpousePreventivePhysicalExam"].ToString();`

Comment: Does that mean I have to repeat the code you suggested 32 times? I have 32 rows and each row has 3 textboxes.